# The Category of (Lie) Algebras is not $k$-linear, right?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, category-theory, lie-algebras, algebras

**1. Context**
In one of my exercise classes I am asked to do the following:
"Verify that Lie algebras (resp. associative algebras) over a field F form an F-linear category LieAlgF (resp. AssocAlgF) with algebra morphisms (resp. Lie algebra morphisms) as morphisms in the category."

**2. My thoughts**
If you define the addition (scalar multiplication) of morphisms via pointwise addition (scalar multiplication) the respective hom-spaces are not vector spaces, however.
That is, these operations are not defined, i.e. the sum of (Lie) algebra morphisms is not necessarily a (Lie) algebra morphism. Similarly, a (Lie) algebra morphism mutiplied by a scalar is not necessarily a (Lie) algebra morphism.

For instance: Let $\mathfrak{g}$ be a non-abelian Lie algebra over a field $\mathbb{F}$ with more than two elements. Consider the Lie algebra morphism $id: \mathfrak{g}\rightarrow \mathfrak{g}$. Let $x,y \in \mathfrak{g}$ such that $[x,y] \neq 0$ and $\lambda \in \mathbb{F} \setminus \{0, 1\}$. Then $[\lambda id(x), \lambda id(y)] =\lambda ^2 \cdot[x,y] \neq \lambda \cdot[x,y] $.

**3. Questions**
Am I overlooking something here? Is there another way to define addition and scalar multiplication on the hom-spaces so that the respective categories becomes $k$-linear?

Comment: You are right. If the claim were true then we could use the Baker–Campbell–Hausdorff formula to make the category of simply connected Lie groups  $\mathbb{R}$-linear!

Comment: Usually morphisms of algebras cannot be added or scaled, which is entirely obvious for unital associative algebras. Removing the unital condition only makes the obstructions very slightly less obvious.